# What is the difference betweeen Zulu Server JDK and Zulu Client JDK for Windows?

Tags: java, azul-zulu

In Zulu JDK download page, there is a Product column for Windows JDK. There are Server and Client for choice. What is the difference of  these two?

[image: Server and Client Product]

Comment: I can see how they can be confusing. They correlate to the **Version** column, but **not the other columns**. Those items in the list support `Windows Server 2016`, `Windows Server 21012R2` etc, also `Windows 10`, `8.1`, `8`, and `7`.  The two downloads (ZIP & MSI) don't actually correspond to the client/server column. You could install the MSI on a Server OS, or use the ZIP on a Client OS.

Comment: BTW, the macOS and Linux sections are much clearer than Windows :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details explanation

Comment: what a coincidence -- it has been fixed today: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will admit this is a bit confusing and will get our web people (I work for Azul) to look at this.

The client and server part refers to the versions of windows that are supported, the downloads are two different formats, either a zip archive or an MSI installer.  Although it looks like the client is associated with the MSI, that's just an artefact of the way the table layout was used.  Either the ZIP or MSI files can be used on either the desktop or server OSs that are supported.

Comment: NB: Zulu download site has just been updated and this bug is one of the fixes.